# LibVLC for android: how to save the playing http stream?

Tags: android, libvlc

Investigating the Java code of the lib, I found no way to save playing video somewhere. However, the VLC core has such capabilities,  according to [this doc](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/), you can duplicate the stream and save it, redirecting it right to the file.

I thought we could supply the corresponding arguments while creating an instance of lib, so I tried to add an option when initializing library in `libvlcjni.c` like that:

> "--sout=duplicate{dst=standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst=/storage/emulated/0/example.mp4},
>   dst=display}"

but seems it's not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concurrently save a playing video to a file using libvlc (at least the following worked for me):

```
final ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
args.add("-vvv");
mLibVLC = new LibVLC(this, args);
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);
<code associating surface for display...>
Media media = new Media(mLibVLC, Uri.parse(SAMPLE_URL));
media.addOption(":sout=#duplicate{dst=file{dst=" + <file name> + "},dst=display}");
mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
mMediaPlayer.play();
```

Comment: Thank you!

It's pretty far though and I'm no longer on that project with VLC=) Happy with that

Answer (score 0):

Guess, currenty there is no way to do it by means of `libvlc`.
However, guys have plans for this feature, [see their milestones at gitlab](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/issues/2)

Comment: --Bagzerg have you found any other way to save some part stream in .mp4 while playing.. Any other lib?.. please give me any idea. i am stuck on that. thanks in advanced.

Comment: I just don't care about that feature now, I simply use DowloadManager. You can use [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) and customize its caching, at least there exists such a possibility, but probably you will have to DIY. One can give a try to find solutions or discuss it in [issues](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues).